# How to use getContentResolver().query() in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Hi I'm trying to get names and phone numbers from contact 
this is the class which extends BroadcastReceiver

```
public class TextMessageReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {            

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

        Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

        for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
            sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }

        for(SmsMessage msg:sms){

            //MainActivity.

            String num = getcont( MainActivity.,msg.getOriginatingAddress());                               

            MainActivity.updateMessageBox("Message de la part: "+msg.getOriginatingAddress()+"\n"+
                    "Qui vous dit: "+msg.getMessageBody()+"\n");        

        }
    }
```

In the Onrecieve methode I get the sms and the the one who send it,but I'd like to get the name not the number after some researche I found this way:

```
public static String getcont (Context context ,String num)
{


    Cursor people = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    String numbr = null;
    while(people.moveToNext()) {
        int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME);
        String contact = people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex);
        int numberFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(PhoneLookup.NUMBER);
        String number = people.getString(numberFieldColumnIndex);
        if (number.equals(num)) {
            numbr = contact;
        }

    }

    people.close();                 
    return numbr;
}
```

I have an Activity called MainActivity I try to call the method getcont()

```
String num = getcont( MainActivity ,msg.getOriginatingAddress());
```

but it show me this error

> MainActivity cannot be resolved to a variable

theres an other way to call `getContentResolver().query()` and thnx for helping me

Answer (score 0):

How about using an intent to navigate to MainActivity?
if I fully understood your requiremnet ...

Instead of doing

```
String num = getcont( MainActivity ,msg.getOriginatingAddress());
```

why not do something like this?

```
Intent ii=new Intent(MainActivity.this, newclass.class);
ii.putExtra("name", s);
startActivity(ii);
```